# important tag not working for inline style in th

Tags: css, inline

I have a slight problem trying to change the colour of my font in a th.

I've the following in my stylesheet

```
th {font-weight:bold;background-color: #C83E02; color: #FFFFFF;padding:5px 3px;border:1px solid #FFFFFF;}
```

and then in one of my TH's, I've got a `<p>` tag with the following inline style

```
<p style="margin:2px;font-size:10px;font-color:#000 !important;font-style:italic;">to</p>
```

My problem is, the font colour isn't overriding! When I check dev tools, it shows that it's being overridden by the style sheet. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS property for font color is called `color`, not `font-color`.

[MDN Color - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color)

Comment: Ah man I'm such a noob! That was a rather rookie mistake. Thanks for that. :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no `font-color` property its just `color`

```
<p style="margin:2px;font-size:10px;color:#000 !important;font-style:italic;">to</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's working

```
<p style="margin:2px;font-size:10px;color:#000;font-style:italic;">to</p>
```